# Distributed transaction between SQL Server and Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures, linked-server

I am having trouble when I begin a transaction and attempt to commit the transaction that is initiated on SQL Server.

```
DECLARE @return_value int,
        @ERROR_MESSAGE nvarchar(2000)

BEGIN TRANSACTION
    EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[SEND_EMAIL]
            @SUBJECT = N'subject',
            @BODY = N'body',
            @RECEIVERS = N'user@email.com',
            @ERROR_MESSAGE = @ERROR_MESSAGE OUTPUT

    SELECT @ERROR_MESSAGE AS N'@ERROR_MESSAGE'

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

    SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

And return this:

> OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "linked_server" returned message "Unable to enlist in the transaction.".
>
> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> Msg 3930, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
>   The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations    that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.
>
> (1 row(s) affected)
>   Msg 3998, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Uncommittable transaction is detected at the end of the batch. The            transaction is rolled back.

My stored procedure in SQL Server is this :

```
BEGIN TRY
    EXECUTE('Call Schema.Package.StoredProcedure(?,?,?,?,?)', @subject, @body, @receivers, @vcSendBy, @ERROR_MESSAGE OUT) AT [linked_server]

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    SET @ERROR_MESSAGE = error_meessage();

END CATCH
```

This work without BEGIN TRANSACTION AND COMMIT but I don't know why.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using a transaction to send email? Transactions are used to keep data in a consistent state. The action of sending an email should not alter the database state.

Comment: the uncommitable transaction is the same problem that I have in a callablestament in Jdeveloper 12c when I try to get some parameters, the code above is a way to reproduce the problem manually

Comment: I solve my problem executing the store procedure in Oracle inside a Function, in my store procedure in SQL Server I call the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my problem executing the stored procedure in Oracle inside a function, in my stored procedure in SQL Server I call the function

```
 FUNCTION FUNCTION_CALL_SP (
           SUBJECT IN VARCHAR2,
           BODY IN CLOB,
           RECEIVERADDRESS IN varchar2,
           send_by IN varchar2
 ) RETURN varchar2 IS 

ERROR_MESSAGE   VARCHAR2(400);

BEGIN

SP_SEND_EMAIL(
    SUBJECT           =>   SUBJECT,
    BODY     =>   BODY,
    RECEIVERADDRESS  =>   RECEIVERADDRESS,
    send_by          =>   send_by,
    ERROR_MESSAGE   =>   ERROR_MESSAGE
);
return ERROR_MESSAGE;
END FUNCTION_CALL_SP ;
```

Now in my stored procedure in SQL Server I have this :

```
   SET @vQuery = 'SELECT @vfResult = A.ERRORMESSAGE FROM OPENQUERY(BCIE,''SELECT SCHEMA.PACKAGE.FUNCTION_SEND_EMAIL('''''+@SUBJECT+''''', '''''+@BODY+''''', '''''+@RECEIVERS+''''', '''''+@SEND_BY+''''') ERRORMESSAGE FROM DUAL'') A';

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL 
              @Query  = @vQuery
            , @Params = N'@vfResult NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT'
            , @vfResult = @vfResul OUTPUT

    SET @ERROR_MESSAGE = @vfResult;
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

And works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the distributed transaction coordinator.  There isn't a simple canned answer for your problem if having your code in a transaction is a requirement.

See the documentation here:  [MSDN Distributed Transactions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/distributedservices/2011/11/28/oracle-transactions-support-with-ms-dtc/)

Here is another good link on the subject:  [DTC](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60858/how-can-i-enable-distributed-transactions-for-a-linked-server)

Answer (score 0):

Since your transaction spans multiple databases you will need to make sure you are using Distributed Transactions. See [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/distributed-transactions-span-sql-server-and-oracle/) on how to configure your server.

After the server is configured, you can start a distributed transaction with the following syntax:

```
BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRAN
    --INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE Data on SQL Server Table
    --INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE Data on Oracle Server Table
COMMIT TRAN
```